# Show text instead of console log

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show the text in a text component instead of console logging it. I have gotten the information in a function and right now it just console logs it. I want to take the information from the function and put it in the state and then display it by grabbing it from the state.

```
state = {
    displayName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
    email: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
    familyName: this.getFamilyName(),
  };

  getFamilyName() {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log(doc.data().familyname);
          return doc.data().familyname;
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 20, fontSize: 14 }}>
              FAMILIE
            </Text>
            <Text h2 style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 20 }}>
              {this.state.familyName}
            </Text>
```

UPDATE. It looks like it doesnt transfer to the state. When I console log the state it says undefined.:

```
state = {
    displayName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
    email: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
    familyName: this.getFamilyName(),
  };

  getFamilyName() {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("1st" + doc.data().familyname);
          const name = doc.data().familyname;
          this.setState({ familyName: name });
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("2nd" + this.state.familyName);
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <View>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 20, fontSize: 14 }}>
                FAMILIE
              </Text>
              <Text h2 style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 20 }}>
                {this.state.familyName}
              </Text>
            </View>
```

OUTPUT

```
2ndundefined
1stVilholm
Error getting document: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **setState** the **familyName**

```
    if (doc.exists) {
          console.log(doc.data().familyname);
          this.setState({'familyName':doc.data().familyname})
        }
```

Now **Text** Component shows you that **familyName**.

```
      <Text h2 style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 20 }}>
          {this.state.familyName&&this.state.familyName}
      </Text>
```

OR

```
      <Text h2 style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 20 }}>
          {this.state?.familyName}
      </Text>
```

**Write your function as arrow function**

```
getFamilyName=()=> {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then((doc)=> {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("1st" + doc.data().familyname);
          const name = doc.data().familyname;
          this.setState({ familyName: name });
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      })}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try this it gives me this error "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `Overlay`, expected a single ReactElement"

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could you try wrapping two Text component with a View

Comment: So there is a problem with getting the information to the view. Im trying to print out the name different places and one of the places its undefined. I will update with code and output in my question.

Comment: @MariusVilholm do you still have problem? Feel free to ask if any :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the inital state with firebase, initialize it to a default value and then you're only missing a setState when you retrieve the information, simply do:

```
state = {
    displayName: firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName,
    email: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
    familyName: '',
  };

  getFamilyName() {
    return firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log(doc.data().familyname);

          const name = doc.data().familyname;
          this.setState({ familyName: name )}

      } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
          <ThemeProvider>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 20, fontSize: 14 }}>
              FAMILIE
            </Text>
            <Text h2 style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 20 }}>
              {this.state.familyName}
            </Text>
```

If you want to handle the error when doc does not exist, you could do this:

```
      } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          this.setState({familyName: false})
        }
      })
```

and then in the render function handle the value of familyName (perhaps with a ternary operator)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I try to use it it gives me this error "Error getting document: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')]"

Comment: This is (maybe, as you didn't post any error lines nor more code) related to doc.data(). Try logging/use the debugger to see doc.data() and its structure, maybe it's empty or the property familyname doesn't exist for that particular document

Answer (score 0):

Use the lifecycle method componentDidMount(). Define the initial state as null strings.

```
state = {
    displayName: '',
    email: '',
    familyName: '',
  };

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({familyName : firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName })
    this.setState({familyName : firebase.auth().currentUser.email })
    this.setState({familyName : this.getFamilyName() })
}
```

If you want to set state elsewhere, you can update the field as

```
this.setState( { familyName : "Your String" } )
```

You can use the state variable as
{this.state.familyName} inside your Text tag to render the view. Note that changing the state variable will automatically re-render the component.

Comment: Thnaks for the answer. When I try to use this it gives me the error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."